# jquery sound notification

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, chat, live

I'm building simple php/mysql/jquery live support chat which includes only 2 files, chat.php and admin.php but I'm stuck with sound notification. How can I receive sound notification in file admin.php when visitor post a message in chat.php. Any help is more than welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a **notify.wav** (or whatever you'd like to use) you can use [soundmanager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) and queue javascript to play the sound when an event has occurred (most likely through the use of AJAX or PUSH notifications)

Comment: Thanks, this is way too much, I'm trying something similar to: $('#sound_element').html("<embed src='"+sound_file_url+"' hidden=true autostart=false loop=false>");

Comment: @Stipe: "Too much"? A 100k plugin that allows you complete sound control? Appending an embedded element for every sound is going to get heavy on the client very fast.

Comment: I was playing a lot with embed elements for sound..but after all I decided to use soundmanager. It has many features you will need, and you can't have with and embed element.